# Why is the normal distribution defined exactly the way it is defined?

Tags: definition, normal-distribution, standard-deviation, gaussian-integral, gaussian

Why is the standard deviation $\displaystyle\sigma$ defined in such a way that in the exponent of the [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution),

$\displaystyle f{{\left({x}\right)}}=\frac{1}{{\sigma\sqrt{{{2}\pi}}}}{e}^{{-{\left(\frac{{{x}-\mu}}{{\sigma\sqrt{{{2}}}}}\right)}^{2}}}$

$\displaystyle \sigma$ needs to be **scaled up** by an additional factor of $\displaystyle\sqrt{{{2}}}$?

Because intuitively, I would define the normal distribution like this, namely simply as the normalized Gaussian integral:

$\displaystyle {\int_{{-\infty}}^{{+\infty}}}{e}^{{-{x}^{2}}}{\left.{d}{x}\right.}=\sqrt{{\pi}}\quad\Rightarrow\quad\displaystyle\ f{{\left({x}\right)}}:\:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{{\pi}}}{e}^{{-{x}^{2}}}$

Comment: Standard deviation makes sense for other distributions besides normal ones.  Even finite data sets have a standard deviation.  Variance is just the average squared distance to the mean...then standard deviation just takes the square root to get the units right.

Comment: @lulu: Yes, I've learned that the standard deviation is basically the RMS (or rather, the square root of the variance) and - for physicists - the square root takes care of the units. But why the factor of $\displaystyle\sqrt{{{2}}}$?

Comment: The square root of $2$ is an artifact of the form of the normal.  You could certainly write the normal without it, but then you would need to supply the factor of $\sqrt 2$ when you tried to read off the standard deviation.  Think how much worse it would be if, instead of the usual variance, statistics had built up around the average absolute difference!  In many ways, that's the more natural measure (why sum the squares and take the square root?)...but, analytically, it is a lot less friendly.

Comment: To stress:  the Central Limit Theorem makes the normal distribution "natural" or even unavoidable, but a priori I don't know why one should have expected that this "limiting" distribution would be conveniently expressed in terms of the standard statistical measures.  A few stray constants here and there is a small price.

Comment: The thing is that $\displaystyle \sigma$ is a general expression, so there is no specific scaling inherent to it and this factor of $\displaystyle\sqrt{{{2}}}$ must somehow originate from the normal distribution itself. There is also this ["68-95-99.7 rule"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) and I always thought that these numbers are rather *arbitrary* - i.e. one could have also just scaled the $\displaystyle{1}\sigma$, $\displaystyle{2}\sigma$, $\displaystyle{3}\sigma$ bands differently (e.g. by said factor of $\displaystyle\sqrt{{{2}}}$)

Comment: The standard deviation is defined as the square root of the variance, there are no arbitrary constants in that. Now, for a distribution with density $A\cdot e^{-cx^2}$, compute the variance and look for which $c$ it is $1$. That happens for $c = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I write it as $(1/\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma) e^{\frac12 (\frac{x - \mu}{\sigma})^2}$. It seems aesthetically a bit odd to me to write it with $\sigma \sqrt{2}$ in the denominator.

Comment: @DanielFischer: You mean this, $\displaystyle{V}{a}{r}{\left({x}\right)}={\int_{{-\infty}}^{{+\infty}}}{\left({x}-\mu\right)}^{2} f{{\left({x}\right)}}={\int_{{-\infty}}^{{+\infty}}}{\left({x}-\mu\right)}^{2}{e}^{{-{c}{\left({x}-\mu\right)}^{2}}}=-{\left({x}-\mu\right)}{e}^{{-{c}{\left({x}-\mu\right)}^{2}}}\stackrel{!}{=}{1}$?

Comment: Essentially. But we must divide by $\int e^{-cx^2}\,dx$ to have a probability density, and we can assume $\mu = 0$.

Comment: @littleO: I wrote it that way, because then it's immediately obvious where the the additional normalization factor comes from (or how one can get rid of it): $\displaystyle{\int_{{-\infty}}^{{+\infty}}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{{\pi}}}{e}^{{-{\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{{{2}}}}\right)}^{2}}}=\sqrt{{{2}}}\quad$ **vs.** $\displaystyle\quad{\int_{{-\infty}}^{{+\infty}}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{{\pi}}}{e}^{{-{x}^{2}}}={1}$.

Comment: Write it $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\,\sigma}\sqrt{\exp \Biggl(-\biggl(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\biggr)^2\Biggr)}\,,$$ problem solved ;)

Comment: Haha...what :D  Okay, I need to go through this...you wrote the $\displaystyle{e}^{{-\frac{1}{{2}}}}$ as $\displaystyle\sqrt{{{e}^{ -{{1}}}}}$, how to use this?

Comment: @DanielFischer Okay, I'm sorry to tell you that your hunch regarding a unit variance was incorrect. The variance computes to 1/2 sqrt(pi / c^3), equating it to 1 would give you c = (pi / 4)^(3/2). So nowhere near 1/2

Comment: @DanielFischer ...actually, for c = 1/2 the variance is sqrt(pi/2) and not 1.

Comment: [Calculate again](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_normal_distribution)

Answer (score 2):

The form $\frac{x^2}{2}$ is rather common in mathematics, often arising from the fact that it's the integral of $x$. For example the formula for kinetic energy is $m\frac{v^2}{2}$, the distance fallen in time $t$ is $g\frac{t^2}{2}$, and the Taylor expansion of $\exp(x)$ is $1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}\dots$. So we shouldn't be afraid when we see

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\exp\left(\frac{\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2}{2}\right).$$

The expression $\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$ is x after being 'normalised' by subtracting off the mean and scaling by the standard deviation, and then squaring and dividing by two is a very standard thing to do.

Comment: Exactly. The pattern $\frac12 z^2$ is very common in math. If you integrate $z$ you get $\frac12 z^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Because the normal distribution is a probability density function. Therefore the integral from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ has to equal one.

$$\displaystyle {\int_{{-\infty}}^{{+\infty}}}\frac{1}{{\sigma\sqrt{{{2}\pi}}}}{e}^{{-{\left(\frac{{{x}-\mu}}{{\sigma\sqrt{{{2}}}}}\right)}^{2}}} = 1 $$

Comment: Yes, but normalization to 1 is already guaranteed by the general form $\displaystyle\frac{1}{{\alpha\sqrt{{\pi}}}}{e}^{{-{\left(\frac{x}{\alpha}\right)}^{2}}}$ :) The question here is, why the $\displaystyle\sqrt{{{2}}}$...maybe Daniel Fischer's comment gives an explanation for this (gotta check this)

Comment: @david If you want the standard deviation to be $\sigma$, then you are forced to choose $\alpha = \sigma \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Yes, but **why**? I'm not looking for the definition of the normal distribution (which I posted in the question), but for an explanation why there is this factor of $\displaystyle\sqrt{{{2}}}$ (and not e.g. $\displaystyle\sqrt{{{3}}}$ or $\displaystyle\sqrt{{\pi}}$ or some other constant)